# How to solve an Inverse differentiation problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse

If f is a one-to-one function where $f(3)=2$ and $f'(3)=6$, what is the value of $(f^{-1})'(2)$?

I am not even sure where to start with this question. I was hoping someone can help

$f$ of $3 =2$ and $f$ prime of $3 = 6$ we need to find the value of the derivative inverse of $f$ of $2$

Comment: Write out in words, or just say out loud to yourself what $(f^{-1})'(2)$ means

Comment: @D.W. i did this in the edits

Comment: There's a well-known formula for the derivative of the inverse in terms of f and its derivative at a point - or you can derive it for yourself by differentiating $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$ by applying chain rule (assuming you've justified that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable).

Comment: I believe what this problem is asking might not be what you think it is asking. This is not differentiation. All we know about $f$ is that it takes 3 to 2 (which means we know $f^{-1}$ takes 2 to 3). I suggest $f'$ is a *different function*, not the derivative. All we know about $f'$ is that it takes 3 to 6 (which means $(f')^{-1}$ takes 6 to 3. This asks for 2 to be sent through the function $f^{-1}$ then that output gets sent through $f'$. 2 goes to 3, 3 goes to 6. $(f^{-1})'(2)=6$. That's why it's important that they stipulated that f is one-to-one, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing $f$ sends $3$  to $2$ and $f^{-1}$ sends $2$ to $3.$ the slopes of $f$ at $2$ and of $(f^{-1})'$ at $3$ are reciprocals. here is one way to see that.

since $f$ has slope $6$ at $x = 3, y = 2.$ if $f$ were a line it would be $y = f(x) = 6(x-3) + 2 = 6x -16.$ the inverse would be $f^{-1}(x)= \frac{1}{6}(x-2)+3$ which has slope $\frac16$ at the point $x = 2, y = 3.$  therefore $$(f^{-1})'(2)= \frac16. $$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$(f^{-1})'(2)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(2))}$$

Comment: $$\displaystyle\frac{1}{6(2)}$$ would this be the answer?

Comment: @Csci319 Nope, because $f^{-1}(2) \neq 2$, so $f'(f^{-1}(2))\neq f'(2)$. Find what $f^{-1}(2)$ equals to first.

Answer (score 1):

This formula comes in handy from time to time, and it's good to know how to derive it on the spot. Let $f$ be such a function where $y = f^{-1}(x)$. Then $f(y)=x$ and by implicit differentiation we have $$f'(y)\cdot y' = 1 \\ \implies y' = \frac{1}{f'(y)}$$ In letting $y = f^{-1}(x)$ we may differentiate both sides to get $y' = (f^{-1}(x))'$ and then we can use these two equations to rewrite  $y' = \frac{1}{f'(y)}$ as $$(f^{-1}(x))' = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$$ The rest of your question can be answered with algebra, as you now have an equation for $(f^{-1}(2))'$ and  you were already given everything you need to solve for it.

Comment: so would it be $\frac{1}{6(3)}$?

Comment: I don't think that is right. I guess the trickiest part is evaluating $f'(f^{-1}(x))$. It helps to start from the inside and work out, so we first need to evaluate $f^{-1}(2)$. What do you get?